# Purpose of piping in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apnagent

Doing this `apnagent` [tutorial](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs) and I do not understand what is the purpose of 'piping' of setting values in the second line.

```
var apnagent = require('apnagent')
  , agent = module.exports = new apnagent.Agent(); // <--- WHY this here
```

---

Especially I do not understand why `module.exports = agent;` needs, if earlier in tutorial there is a line like this:

```
module.exports = "<a1b56d2c 08f621d8 7060da2b c3887246 f17bb200 89a9d44b fb91c7d0 97416b30>";
```

Why does `module.exports` need to be overwritten?

Comment: It's short for `agent = new apnagent.Agent(); module.exports = agent;`.

Comment: Why module.exports need to be overwrite?

Comment: @János it's in different files.

Comment: @Tomalak There is no comma operator in the shown snippet? It's a multiple variable declaration and an assignment expression.

Comment: @Bergi The comma in a multiple variable assignment is not the comma operator? I always thought so.

Comment: @Tomalak, no, if it was the comma operator it would be interpreted as `var apnagent = (require('apnagent'), agent = …);` which does something quite different.

Comment: I see. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really piping, actually, there's no `|` (pipe) as in the Unix world.

This pattern makes sure `new apnagent.Agent()` is accessible in both the local scope with `agent` and through `require` via `module.exports`.

It's exactly the same as doing:

```
 var agent = new apnagent.Agent();
 module.exports = agent;
```

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` can exports your code

`new apnagent.Agent();` make a new agent object

`agent = module.exports = new apnagent.Agent();`

and

`module.exports = new apnagent.Agent();
agent = module.exports`

they are equals.

**`Module.exports` point to a new object, `agent` disconnect with the `module.exports` reference, then through `agent = module.exports` to re-export `module.exports`.**

Agent and assign it to module.exports so we can access it from all or our different playground scenarios.